# JPA/Hibernate query: load eagerly with subselect

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

**Situation**: "Parent" entity has multiple "Child" entities (@OneToMany, @Lazy) - two way relationship. No foreign key ("Child#parentId") field on entity.

**Goal**: Avoid N+1 problem by retrieving fully loaded Parent collection using sub-selects. If I understand theory of Subselect, this is my goal (2 resulting SQL queries):

```
select * from Parent ...;
select * from Child where parent_id in ...;
```

**Question 1**: What is the best practice to achieve this? Could you provide examples in both JPQL/HSQL and Criteria?

**Question 2 (bonus)**: Can API manage second query division into "batches" - e.g. limit batches to 500: if 1st query loads 1000 Parents, 2a. loads Children for 500 Parents, 2b. loads for next 500.

**I have tried**:
Both result in SQL JOINs, it seems that I cannot use Child's foreign key without JOIN.

```
// 2nd query:
criteria
.createAlias("parent", "p")
.add(Property.forName("p.id")
        .in(parentCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("id"))))
.list();

// 2nd query (manual):
criteria
.createAlias("parent", "p")
.add(Property.forName("p.id").in(parentIdList))
.list();
```

### Update (2015-04-05)

I checked that what it indeed works in EclipseLink via hints:

```
query.setHint("eclipselink.batch.type", "EXISTS");
```

This link http://blog.ringerc.id.au/2012/06/jpa2-is-very-inflexible-with-eagerlazy.html suggests that this is not possible via Hibernate and suggests manual fetching. However I cannot understand how to achieve it via HQL or Criteria, specifically how to get child.parent_id column that is not on Entity, but exists only on Database. That is, avoiding JOIN that would result from child.parent.id.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid N+1 queries you can annotate relationship with

```
@BatchFetch(BatchFetchType.JOIN)  //in eclipselink or
@BatchSize //in hibernate.
```

Inside queries, you can add fetch to join clause:

```
select p from Parent p join fetch p.children c where ...
```

You can add also query hints

```
query.setHint("eclipselink.batch", "p.children");
```

Or use EntityGraphs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this info, but this is not exactly what I am looking for. Entity mapping cannot be changed and as for join fetching, it works, but I am trying to specifically avoid any SQL JOINs here.

Comment: Then you should try queryhints. Finally, there is not reason to be afraid of joins. It took me awhile to overcome it and a some testing, but parent/child joins are index joins so they are fast, in reality db invokes same code and access the same data as in separate query limited to parent id. So typically join query will be faster than the two separate 'optmized ones'. Test it yourself.

Comment: There are other reasons to want to avoid joins.  For instance, eager fetching multiple relationships will cause a cartesian product that can get large quickly.  Also, joins do not play nicely with pagination.